# How to use a MySQL command in VB2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a button where I want this **MySQL command** to be executed: **"update ix.masterlist set DIVISION = replace(DIVISION,'01','HRD')"**

How do I go about doing this?

This is what I have in my code but it is not doing anything.

```
    Try
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
        Dim strsql As String
        strsql = "update ix.masterlist set DIVISION = replace(DIVISION,'01','HRD')"
        cmd.CommandText = strsql
        dataAdap.SelectCommand = cmd
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Repclaced the Records")
    End Try
```

Comment: I don't see any MySqlConnection in your code. Without connection your command will fail.

Comment: There is one on my code, and it works for other commands.I just did not include it in the code that I pasted.